# Is it possible to recover MongoDB databases from .ns and .0, .1, . ... files?

Tags: ubuntu, database, mongodb

I have a MongoDB 2.0.4 installation on Ubuntu 12.10. Recently I had some problems connecting to the database from the outside, and figured out there was something which prevented MongoDB from starting correctly. As suggested on several sources (see StackOverflow) I removed `/var/lib/mongodb/mongodb.lock` and ran `mongod --repair`. This didn't solve the problem, MongoDB wouldn't run and kept creating lock files that it didn't take care of removing afterwards. By looking at the logs, I realized that it didn't have access to some folder called `$tmpSomething`, so (since the name suggested a temporary folder) I removed it, and afterwards it all worked ... except the fact that I only have one of my previous databases in sight, while the other ones are still there because my `/var/lib/mongodb/` folder is still full of `.ns .0 .1 .n` files that weight a lot. Is there a way to restore them into the database? (I have tried with mongorestore, but as I was expecting, it doesn't handle those files).

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `.ns .0 .1` etc. files are the data files themselves.  If you started a `mongod` instance with a `--dbpath` argument pointing at that folder, or if you moved the contents somewhere else and used the option to point there, mongod will attempt to read them as normal.

Since your issues suggest corruption and/or some other issue starting `mongod` (you should really post the startup messages log files, perhaps in a separate question to address that issue), then there are alternatives.  For reference, the most common problems are permissions related, especially when people try to start mongod manually (as themselves) or with sudo (as root) and create problematic permissions in the various directories.

You are correct that `mongorestore` cannot use these data files directly, but `mongodump` can read them and dump data from them into the BSON files that `mongorestore` expects.

The option you want here is [dbpath](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodump/#cmdoption-mongodump--dbpath).  You mention your path is `/var/lib/mongo`, so you can run something like this:

```
mongodump --dbpath /var/lib/mongo -d <database name> -o /path/to/put/files
```

Optionally you can use `--repair` here too to fix corruption along with the query options in extreme circumstances to get around corrupted sections (rarely, if ever, needed).  The various options are described on the `mongodump` page:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodump/

Once you dump the files out, you can use `mongorestore` to reimport them into another `mongod` instance.

Comment: Mongodump 3.0+ [no longer has the --dbpath flag](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#options).

Comment: correct, you will notice that the question was asked about version 2.0.4 - mongodump will only support repair for the MMAP engine now too - with later versions and in particular with WiredTiger you are limited to the repair option with mongod, mongodump is no longer an option

Comment: With Mongo 3.0 an option is to start the mongo server with specified files: `mongod --dbpath ./` and then proceed with the mongodump without the `--dbpath`

Comment: Just a note, if you are running Mongo 3.0 and `mongod --dbpath ./` does not give you the database in the `.ns .0` files, it could be that the storage engine is defaulting to the new WiredTiger engine instead of the old MMapV1 engine. Try `mongod --storageEngine mmapv1 --dbpath ./` instead to connect using the old engine.

Comment: Can anybody help me migrating the data from .ns, .0 and .1 files to mongo 3.0

Comment: As @flamebaud said, the default engine has changed. Please check [Default Storage Engine Change](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2-compatibility/#storage-engine-compatibility) in the Mongo documentation. You may also want to have a look at the beginning of the document at [WiredTiger Storage Engine](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/)